# Retrieve an element of an orderedcollection in pharo

Tags: pharo

I have a difficult problem.
I have a method that return an OrderedCollection(an orderedCollection(String),an orderedCollection(String), an orderedCollection(Date)).

I want to have this result an orderedCollection(String, String, Date). How Can i do ?

Comment: **Hint:** Not difficult. To do those kinds of things `#collect:` is your friend. However, why you have such a collection in the first place?

Comment: well in fact I would like to retrieve the type of a variable using the RoelTyper tool. when I have only one variable, there is no problem. on the other hand, if I have several variables, to recover all the types, I use an orderedcollection otherwise, I have the type of the last variable only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your composite collection only includes subcollections with one element, you can use

```
result := theCollection collect: [:sc| sc first]
```

where `theCollection` stands for your `OrderedCollection` of `OrderedCollections`.

Otherwise, if the subcollections do not meet this condition and you want to put all elements into a single collection use

```
result := theCollection gather: [:sc | sc]
```

For example:

```
#(#(1) #(2) #(3)) collect: [:sc | sc first]
```

will give as `result` the `Array` `#(1 2 3)` (similarly for `OrderedCollection`s).

On the other hand

```
#(#(1 2) #(3) #(4 5 6)) gather: [:sc | sc]
```

will produce `#(1 2 3 4 5 6)`.